# How to load a file before composer and /vendor/autoload.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, composer-php, phpunit

I need to load Wordpress wp-load.php before the vendor/autoload.php and Laravel.

I can update in the `public/index.php` but at PHPUnit level the `vendor/bin/phpunit` loads `vendor/autoload.php` before the `wp-load.php`.

Is it possible to force composer to load a file before anything else ?

I tried

```
{
    "autoload" : {
         "files" : ["public/wordpress/wp-load.php"]
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seems to work as composer loads Laravel before wordpress...

The only ugly fix I found is to manually load wp-load in the vendor/autoload.php file but I need to do that at every composer update.

Answer (score 3):

Composer is not responsible for loading `autoload.php`, but the whatever framework you are using is. PHPUnit, in your case.

PHPUnit only loads `vendor/autoload.php` because that file is bootstrapped in `phpunit.xml` configuration.

Much easier than doing any weird injection during composer run is simply to create your own testing bootstrap file.

If you check `phpunit.xml` you'll find a bootstrap declaration which by default loads `vendor/autoload.php`:

```xml
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
stopOnFailure="false">
```

Create a new bootstrap file (e.g. `testing_bootstrap.php`) and there include whatever files you need in addition to `vendor/autoload.php`:

```php
<?php
// testing_bootstrap.php

require 'path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php`;
```

And modify your `phpunit.xml` file so it uses **this** file to bootstrap your tests.

```
bootstrap="testing_bootstrap.php"
```

This is cleaner and more maintainable, and accomplishes the right result. Which files are loaded/bootstrapped before execution is not composer's job.

---

To accomplish the same during a regular Laravel run, you'll need to modify Laravel's [entry point file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php), you'll find there that autoload is required there:

```php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

If you want to load a different file **before** autoload, simply add the appropriate `require` or `include` statement before that point.

E.g.:

```php
require 'path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php';
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Using the `files` key of composer will simply **not work**. These files are loaded on `vendor/composer/autoload_files.php` file, and this in turn is loaded on `vendor/composer/autoload_real.php::getLoader`, **after** the rest of the autoloading process setup has been performed.

---

Comment: Hi @yivi, the problem is that I use PHPUnit for unit testing and it has an other loader entry point than the Laravel... => For the moment I managed to hack that with a after-composer update script to inject wp-load.php before vendor/autoload.php

Comment: Ok, updated my answer to account for the fact that you need this during tesitng, although the approach is the same. @injetkilo

Answer (score -1):

The fix I found for the moment is to apply a php script right after the composer autoload dump (in scripts post-autoload-dump) => it does the trick.

Comment: Can you explain that further such that others can learn from your answer?